# What to use for Paypal Parallel Payments with php

Tags: php, paypal

I am writing a script to split payments to sellers using parallel payments with php.
Previously I have used the 'pay' sdk with adaptive payments.

On the developer site it now states:

Important: Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal.

I am in the uk and marketplace is for US only at present.
So what am I to use?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can utilize Express Checkout with Parallel Payment.

Refer [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the link, It also states that : Express Checkout - NVP/SOAP (Deprecated) And if i write script for this it will be unsupported soon?

Comment: It is not so soon because any deprecated API will be replace by other API but up until now, PayPal hasn't finalize yet the substitution API for the Parallel payment.

Comment: Hi Thanks, i will take a look. Do you know if you can do express checkout as a straight through 'pay' without doing the review step in the middle.

Comment: Did you mean skipping the GetExpressCheckout? Yes you can. GetExpressCheckout is optional by the way. After SetEC then DoEC.